# MVC custom routing is not working when there are lots of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am facing lot of problem while setting custom route in MVC

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
                "SearchList",
                "Search/{city}/{cat}", // URL
                new
                {
                    controller = "Search",
                    action = "Index"

                }, // URL Defaults
               new { id = @"\d+" }
            );
```

SearchController

```
public ActionResult Index(string city, string search, string cat, int? pageNo, string ratio, string fee, string curr, int? id)
```

This method is for Searching particular items with filters on it.

I tried lots of permutation combination but was unsuccessful.

I need below type of result:

```
http://localhost/Search/City/Category
http://localhost/Search/City
http://localhost/Search/Category
http://localhost/Search/Curr
```

I am getting "A public action method 'pune' was not found on controller 'App.Web.Controllers.SearchController'." error when I enter below url:

```
http://localhost:5355/Search/pune/Preschool
```

Comment: It sounds a little like you left the default routepath in the route config file before the path you are actually trying to use.  this would cause the error you are seeing since the url fits the pattern of the default route config

Answer (score 1):

Your searches really should not use route-level parameters, but rather should use the querystring. That's what it's there for, *query*ing.

You're going to run into problems using route parameters for your search because with MVC routes, **only the last route parameter can be made optional**. All the rest are required.

You are going to be better off with a URL that looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:5355/Search?City=pune&Category=Preschool
```

@theDarse is right about the exception message you are seeing though. Somewhere in your route config, you have the default route. Make sure it gets defined *after* your `SearchList` route.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using Area, It can be easier that way instead I am not sure if you can do it that way, I have never done it.